# error: package com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager does not exist,xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

obj\Debug\android\src\mono\com\google\android\gms\common\images\ImageManager_OnImageLoadedListenerImplementor.java(52,52): Error:  error: package com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager does not exist

com.google.android.gms.common.images.ImageManager.OnImageLoadedListener

i checked the path and there is a file in this path.but when building the project i get this error, have anyone come across this issue? any solution for this?